# Windows 10 stopped locking, sleeping and turning off the fans at all

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, fan, lid

My laptop with W10 stopped turning off the fans in sleep mode or lock unless i shut it down. I think that it's because something interrupts the sleep process and so it never is **fully** asleep, so it doesn't lock the laptop or turn off the fans/disks. Before, it used to be that closing the lid would make the PC quiet in a few seconds and lock it which is the behaviour I want.

I would appreciate some help.

Edit: Unplugging all devices and retrying brings the same effect.

Comment: Any external peripherals plugged in the USB ports or in wireless mode (mouse, external HDD/SSD, keyboard, etc...)?

Comment: Yes, headphones, mouse and cooling pad. But that didn't used to be a problem... Some people also suggested closing all the programs but then what's the point o making it sleep and not shut down? I'll try without anything plugged in.

Comment: It was worth a try, right? If you go into Power management in Control Panel and check the Advanced power options, do you see one relating to triggers allowing your PC to resume when in standby/sleep mode? If so, disable them completely, in both AC and DC. You don't have a newly-added or reset program running in the background that could prevent your PC from going to sleep? No BitTorrent client running minimized to tray? Those applications are often set by default to prevent the PC from going to sleep while downloading and/or seeding.

Comment: Aw shit thank you so much! Yes i recently got a download manager, how could i have not thought of that! God damn it thanks.

Comment: LOL! Hey, no sweat. Glad it worked out for you. Cheers mate!

Comment: Cheers! Thanks for the help.

Comment: It would be great if @Didier posts the comment as an answer, and it gets accepted, for the benefit of the community.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio: Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into Power management in Control Panel and check the Advanced power options, do you see one relating to triggers allowing your PC to resume when in standby/sleep mode? If so, disable them completely, in both AC and DC.

You don't have a newly-added or reset program running in the background that could prevent your PC from going to sleep? No BitTorrent client running minimized to tray? Those applications are often set by default to prevent the PC from going to sleep while downloading and/or seeding.